# Webpack cannot find properly path for slick files

Tags: javascript, html, webpack, slick.js

I started to using a webpack bundler, and I got a little issue with slick slider.
Slick fonts and gif doesn't load properly

It looks like webpack skips main folder, where my project is, and looking for files in d:/node_modules instead of d:/main_folder/node_modules
I was trying to fix this by creating slick-fix.scss and set font and loader path
but it doesn't work properly

This is the error screenshot:

[image]

slick-fix.scss

```
$slick-loader-path: "/node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/" !default;
$slick-font-path: "/node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/fonts/" !default;
```

main.scss

```
@import "slick-fix";
@import "~slick-carousel/slick/slick.scss";
@import "~slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.scss";
```

main.js

```js
require('./styles/main.scss');
require('jquery');
import 'slick-carousel/slick/slick';
$('.slider').slick();
```

```js
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const webpack = require('webpack');
const $ = require('jquery');


module.exports = {
    context: path.resolve(__dirname),
    entry: './src',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'main.js'
    },
    mode: 'development',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                    options: {
                        presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "html-loader",
                        options: { minimize: true }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader',
                    'sass-loader',
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/i,
                use: [
                  {
                    loader: 'url-loader',
                    options: {
                      limit: 8192,
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
            template: "./src/index.html",
            filename: "./index.html"
        }),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            'window.$': 'jquery',
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
          })
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access local paths from your http server. In other words, you cannot load files from your harddrive directly. They have to be served by the server.

Comment: So what im suposed to do, install loader, change path?

Comment: You have to use an HTTP server to run your app.

Comment: Try `webpack-dev-server`